# Script only runs once, even though I'm using "while(True)"

Tags: python, while-loop

I'm working on a Python script that goes into a given directory and deletes files based on modification date. I've gotten most of it to work (surprisingly!), except I found a bug.  Let me give you all some insight into how my program works.

So, if the user requests that the program runs quietly, I have all of the stdout and stderr information being redirected to a temp text file in a temp folder.  Works just fine.  There is also an option to run the script continuously.  I used a simple while(True) loop to accomplish this.  Running continuously worked all fine and dandy, until I wanted to delete that temporary folder after each loop.  Here is the code in my main function:

```
    while(True):

        display()
        verifyDirectory()
        checkArgs()            
        # Deleting the temporary folder after each loop:
        if args.q:
            deleteTempFolder()
```

Again, everything worked fine until I tried deleting the temp folder after each loop.  The program basically stops after the first loop is completed.  Here is the code under the deleteTempFolder():

```
# Closing the redirected text files.
sys.stdout.close()
sys.stderr.close()

# Defining the paths for the temp folder and the existing text files.
folder = args.directory + "\\" + "temp"
stdoutPath = folder + "\\" + "stdout.txt"
stderrPath = folder + "\\" + "stderr.txt"

# Deleting the text files first, then deleting the entire temporary folder.
os.remove(stdoutPath)
os.remove(stderrPath)
os.rmdir(folder)
```

I should also note that all of the above code works fine on its own, but when I combined the two (run continuously and delete the temporary folder), that's when I noticed that I break out of my loop.

Also, no errors or exceptions are being generated.  I was able to check the stderr file by redirecting it to another location, so it wouldn't be deleted when I ran the code.

I hope all of this makes sense.  This is the first time I've asked a question on here, and this is the first script I've ever written that wasn't a silly video game in Java for a course.  I'm hoping to post the entire script later for advice on efficiency!

Comment: Do you recreate the folder at the beginning of each loop?  Otherwise it's probably failing because you're trying to remove something that doesn't exist.

Comment: My primary suspicion is that an exception _is_ being generated, but it's not showing up in your redirected stderr for some reason. Could you delete anything that modifies `sys.stdout` or `sys.stderr`, and see what the output is on the console?

Comment: Wow!  You guys are fast!  @Dannnno: The folder does get recreated when the checkArgs() function is called.  When I don't call deleteTempFolder(), the program runs continuously and just appends to the same file over and over again.  If I let the program run for a few minutes, the stdout.txt file gets rather large.  So, I thought it would be more efficient to delete after each loop.  I'm wondering if I should post the entire script here, but I thought that might be a no-no.

Comment: @Kevin: Delete anything that modifies them?  Do you mean that I should temporarily not redirect them?  Perhaps just delete an empty blank folder?  Sorry, I'm not following...

Comment: I'd recommend debugging it, remove all the redirections and run `pdb.set_trace()` where you think it's breaking. I think Kevin is right, an exception must be happening.

Comment: @Kevin: I just tried that.  Everything prints to the console just fine.  No errors or exceptions.

Comment: @KurzedMetal: I've never used that before.  I will look it up and give it a shot.  I'll get back to ya!

Comment: Do you have a line that puts stderr back anywhere? (something like `sys.stderr = sys.__stderr__`)

Comment: @NightShadeQueen Ah, no I do not.  Perhaps that should happen before I loop again?

Comment: @Dannnno : It turns out that you were correct.  I was not recreating the folder in the loop.  Once I was able to see the errors that were generating, I traced my problem back to that "newbie" error.  Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2):

There is probably an exception being thrown but not displayed because the error stream is closed. Try this code (`python boom.py`) and comment out the `sys.stderr.close()` line:

```
import sys

print("Hello, world")

# this will prevent displaying the exception
sys.stderr.close()

# NameError: name 'nosuchfunction' is not defined
nosuchfunction

print("Goodbye, world")
```

Comment: Ok, I'm seeing some exceptions now.  When I keep the line sys.stdout.close(), I'm getting "I/O operation on closed file".  When I comment that line out, I get "The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process".  I noticed that this error happens when I keep the os.remove(stdoutPath) and os.rmdir(folder).  Without those three lines, the code works fine... minus the fact that it doesn't actually do what I want lol :)

Comment: That was very helpful, thank you!  I was able to see the exceptions, and I figured out my problem!

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the solution to my problem, thanks to all of the feedback here.  It turns out that I my program was generating errors, but I was unable to see until I commented out sys.stderr.close().  Once I could see where and when the program was crashing, I figured out that I was never recreating the temp folder in my loop, which is slightly embarrassing!  Thanks for all the feedback!